# How to export Google "My places" map, now that the KML button is missing

Tags: google-maps

I am used to using the KML button in Google maps to export my saved maps, as instructed in [Export My Map as KML](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapstips/export-my-map-as-kml) - which I got to from Google's own [Maps data liberation](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/maps) page.

Having not done this since 5th July, as of today I can no longer see the KML button:

[image]

I've tried clicking in the link button, but it just pops up a dialog that supplies a URL, and gives me text to paste into website.

Am I missing something obvious? Or has Google just removed the ability to liberate one's Maps data now?

Or is there an unadvertised way to extract the data?

- Web browser: Firefox 14.0.1
- OS: Windows 7 Pro

Comment: I just tried accessing My Places, clicked the "Edit" button and got the same screen, but once I clicked "Done", the KML link is there and working. Perhaps something in your browser is blocking it. Have you tried another browser?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy D'oh. Thanks! You're right - do you want to add it as an answer, and I'll accept it - in case it helps others in the same situation.

Comment: Answer added. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried accessing My Places, clicked the "Edit" button and got the same screen, but once I clicked "Done", the KML link is there and working. Perhaps something in your browser is blocking it. Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Erm, yes - clicking "Done" solved the problem. Blush!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue. I found out the following:

Even though the KML image and link were not present in Chrome, I saw them in Firefox.

In Chrome, I looked at the source to see if these elements were simply hidden, but I didn't find them at all.

Then I disabled all of my Chrome extensions, reloaded the map, and the KML options were finally present, as in this screen shot:

[image]

I tried to isolate which of the extensions was responsible -- but I was not able to figure that out: Even after re-enabling all of my extensions, and reloading the Google Maps page, the KML options continued to be present.

Comment: Thanks. I think you can probably post screenshots now, with rep of 11.

Comment: Indeed I can now -- and I have. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Note that a manual option for exporting to KML is now available in the new Create Map interface for the new Google Maps (Map Engine Light). Find it under the little folder icon.

Comment: this solved it for me with the new interface.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question already has an answer, but I just came across this problem myself, and Joe answered it for me.  The only thing that is actually needed is a refresh of the page though.  The steps to reproduce the problem are:

1. Create a new map
2. Save it and click done

The KML link will be missing.  All that is necessary to see it is a page refresh.  Note also that any changes that you make to your saved map will require a refresh for the KML to be up-to-date.  The KML link will be as old as your most recent refresh.

Comment: perhaps you could suggest this as an edit

Comment: You should earn a +1, but I agree with @axrwkr.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new.  How do I suggest it as an edit?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"the little folder icon"

As of March 2014

1)Make Map

2)Name Map Layer

3) Click "the little folder icon"

4) Select Export to XML from drop down menu

5) Choose layer from step 2

6) Press download and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Export your own map:

- Click the map menu button [image: three dots] in the left panel.
- Select Export as KML.

Export the data of a map shared with you (i.e. you don't have permission to edit it):

- In the legend, click the share button [image: a circle connected to two circles].
- Select Download KML.

Source: [My Maps Help - Export a map](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452)